# Trying to get details of posts in single page

Tags: php, laravel

i am trying to get the details of a post content in  a single page and i have this  in my web.php

```
Route::get('/{category}/{post}','PropertyController@show')->name('posts.show');
```

and i have this in my controller

```
public function show(Property $property)
    {
        $title = "Single Post";
        return view('properties.show', compact('title','property'));
    }
```

also in my blade i have this `<h4>{{$property->title}}</h4>`

But it is showing empty tag without showing the title

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: if you are going to use route model binding you will want the route parameter name and the variable name for the method to match, otherwise you will just get a new instance of a model as a dependency ... `post != property`

Answer (score 0):

The variable name doesn't match the method 
You can update your code to make it match and then pass the title as element of the array property.

```
  public function show($post)
    {
      //Use the $post to get property info
      $property = [] //you can fetch this from your db
      $property['title'] = "Single Post";
      return view('properties.show', compact($property,'property'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show title in your html like :

```
<h4>{{$title}}</h4>
```